# To view and manage your registrations for converged applications

Tags: azure

[image]I see the following message "To view and manage your registrations for converged applications, please visit the Microsoft Application Console." (screenshot) under AD app registration screen in Azure Portal? what is this all about?

Clicking on that link takes me to a different page where I can perform App Registrations, trying to understand the difference between registering in Azure portal and in other external site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Microsoft has released a new feature in Azure Authentication to support Microsoft account and Organisation account authentication in a single Azure Active Directory v2 authentication endpoint.

Here is the link for the complete article https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/02/23/for-developers-the-first-use-cases-of-the-converged-microsoft-account-and-azure-active-directory-programming-model-are-now-ga/

## Key extract from the article

Today I am excited to tell you that the first set of uses cases supported by the Azure Active Directory v2 authentication endpoint are generally available. With the v2 endpoint, you can now build applications that let users sign in using their Azure AD backed work, or school account, or their Microsoft Account using a single button.

Federated sign in has many benefits. If you accept sign ins from Microsoft, you can:

- Store fewer passwords in your application and make yourself a less attractive target for attackers,
- Avoid your users having to remember another name and password,
  Give your users a single sign on experience if they are already signed in to Windows 10, Office 365, Outlook.com, OneDrive, or other Microsoft property,
- Seamlessly integrate a user’s data such as their calendar or contacts,
- Take advantage of Microsoft’s advanced anomalous sign in detection technology, and let us help you defend your user’s accounts.

With federated sign in, Microsoft can handle identity management for you. With the Azure Active Directory v2 endpoint, we’re making this easier than ever before. Until now, building an application that worked with both Microsoft work and school accounts and Microsoft personal accounts required adding two technology stacks to your application: the Microsoft account stack and the Azure Active Directory stack. We’re bringing these two systems together so that you can integrate once and enable both kinds of users to sign in using a single button:

This converged programming model is exposed by the Azure AD v2 authentication endpoint. Today we are excited to announce GA of the first two scenarios supported by the v2 endpoint: